# Вычитание / сложение дат C# в пределах 5-дневного рабочего дня

Tags: c#, datetime

Мне нужно произвести условное вычитание и сложение дат, а так же условное вычитание и сложение минут. Опишу что имею ввиду:

В неделе 5 рабочих дней (Пн - Пт). В эти дни есть рабочие часы (10 - 18).

Мне нужно производить ряд операций:

```
 1. (DT_1-DT_1).TotalMinutes
 2. DT.AddMinutes(minutes)
```

Как бы наиболее просто реализовать это ? Пробовал с методами расширения но получается очень громоздко и запутано...

Мне нужно следующее к примеру:

> DT_1 = 2019.01.11 18:00:00.000 (Пт)
>
> DT_2 = 2019.01.12 10:00:00.000 (Сб)
>
> minutes = 60 (1 час)
>
> (DT_1-DT_).TotalMinutes_custom = 0
>
> (DT_2-DT_1).TotalMinutes_custom =0
>
> DT_1.AddMinutes_custom(minutes)= 2019.01.14 11:00:00.000
>
> DT_2.AddMinutes_custom(-minutes) = 2019.01.11 17:00:00.000

Быть может кто нибудь знает как подобное реализовать наиболее просто и красиво ? Или же быть может уже есть встроенное решение ?

Comment: @nick_n_a Нет не оно. Мс пример. Мне нужно что бы при расчетах учитывалось рабочее время и рабочие дни. т.е. если последний рабочий час = 18 а начальный = 10 то AddMinutes(60) должно показать не 19 а 11 часов. а если бы добавляем к Пт то должно было быть не 11 асов Сб а 11 часов Пн.

Comment: Не вижу в вопросе Вашего *сложного* и *некрасивого*  решения. Встроенного решения нет.

Comment: Я понял. Ваша задача не касается дат. Забудте про даты. Я бы... я бы предложил решить вам задачу используя массив. У вас 40-часовая рабочая нелеля? Тогда у вас деление на 40 и остаток от 40 - распределяется на день недели и часы - это в массив.

Comment: @nick_n_a приведите пожалуйста пару строчек примера. Похоже то что Вы написали мне как раз подойдет, однако я не до конце уловил суть.

Comment: У вас 40-часовая рабочая неделя? Создали массив hours40 на 40 - расписали часы по дням - каждый час.   А как по-другому? И поменяйте заголовок - на более красивый.

Comment: @nick_n_a Не понятно на счет деления. 
В Массиве 40 ячеек - 40 часов. или 2400 (2400 минут) 

Что Вы имели ввиду под делением на 40 и остаток от деления?

Comment: Ну да. 40 часов. Каждый час отдельно. Если ПН с 9-18 то ПН 9, ПН 10, ПН 11.... ПН 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас 40-часовая рабочая неделя.

Тогда что... вам нужно расписать ваше время внутри этой недели.

Тогда нужно

```
struct DAYS40{ DayOfWeek day;  int hour; };

List<DAYS40> days40; // TODO: задать дни и часы 40 штук

// Тогда у нас 40-ричная система счисления)))
// Если мы берем i = от нуля до 39 - это внутри недели.
// 40 - новая неделя, тогда...
```

Каждый час отдельно. Если ПН с 9-18 то ПН 9, ПН 10, ПН 11.... ПН 17 ВТ 8.... ПТ 9 ... ПТ 15 наверно так.
Тогда ваша прибавка будет выглядеть так.

```
 DateTime AddHour(DateTime dt, int hour) {
     DAYS40 item;          
     item.day = dt.DayOfWeek;
     item.hour = dt.hour;
     i = days40.indexOf(item);
     if (i == -1) throw new Exception(""); // Придумать что-то
     // вот і это текущая позиция.
     int dayfrom = (int)days40[i].day;
     i = i +  (hour % 40); // меняем позицию.
     int weeks = (hour / 40) +  (i / 40); // Дни 
     // Первое слагаемое - ясно, второе слагаемое-если прошло 7 дней.
     // Получились к-во недель
     i = i % 40; // и часы в 40-часовой системе
     // Ну... теперь можно переводить.
     int dayto = (int)days40[i].day;
     return dt.Date.AddDays(7*weeks + dayto - dayfrom)
      .AddHours(days40[i].hour); 
      // Думаю минуты не нужны 
      // отрицательная разница dayto-dayfrom компенсируется слагаемым (i/40)
     }
```

Но ваше dt - должно быть в рамках 40-часовой системы, если это не так - то нужно уточнять задачу.

А да. Разница в часах... то же, переводим в 40-ричную систему, и вычитаем.
Находим два индекса i и j (так как выше). Тогда ответ в часах будет...   `(TotalDays / 7)*40 + j - i`

А дальше... дальше можно как-то нормировать день. Можно найти min и max час в дне... и... либо вычитать "лишний остаток", либо переносить его на следующий день... думаю имея такой массив - это не тяжело сделать.

Да... такой метод не учитывает празничные дни и переносы, отрабатывание по субботам и т п. Нужно создать ещё одну таблицу - массив НомерРабочегоДня-День-Месяц-Год и через неё считать к-во дней, а не через сквозной календарь. Например сделать `Dictionary<DateTime,int>` days и вести "календарь рабочих дней" в базе данных. Только расчётные данные не должны менятся - потому что интервалы не совпадут. Тогда расстояние между днями "грубо" будет `days[d2.date]-days[d1.date]`, а в предложеном выше методе - прийдётся вместо AddDays использовать такой массив, и через индексы вычислять расстояние в днях.

Comment: ТС нужны манипуляции с `DateTime`, в которых значения `DateTime` могут быть любыми, но время "идет", только если оно рабочеее. *Просто и красиво* не получится.

Comment: Ну... дополнить "нормированием" теоретически можно... но тогда результат будет очень интересным - точнее в рамках нормы. Мне кажется что бухгалтерская задача - узнать сколько часов работал работник - интересная... А время идет... не совсем понятно.

Comment: Благодарю за пример.

Comment: Чуть поправил, я дважды учел переход через неделю - удалил if.

Comment: @Igor Ага. А как только ТС вспомнит о такой вещи, как производственный календарь (переносы выходных дней и праздники) совсем просто и красиво не получится вообще никак.

Comment: Я про производственный календарь не думал. Думаю решается, только прийдётся массив делать не на 40, а на больше (40*52*года, и добавить число месяц год), с возможностью редактировать "будущий" календарь (расчётные данные менять нельзя), потому что для каждого года то тут праздники, то там. Либо делать "вложеность", отдельно массив дней, и ссылку на 40-часовый массив.